# Should a new variable be used for each addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html

I was reading a book on adding event listeners to HTML elements and I noticed that all of the var are called formElement and then the next one is also form element. Can you use the same variable everytime or should you use a different variable name every time. The document-getElementById("textBox") assigns that value of the HTML element to the variable and then addEventListener with a keyup event.

**Question: Should a different variable be used for each addEventListner()?**

From what I see that you can just keep using the same variable over and over again and attaching the keylistener(...) to the new addEventListener(...)

Code:

```
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d"); 

var formElement = document.getElementById("textBox");
formElement.addEventListener('keyup', textBoxChanged, false);   

var f = document.getElementById("fillOrStroke");
f.addEventListener('change', fillOrStrokeChanged, false);   

formElement = document.getElementById("textSize");
formElement.addEventListener('change', textSizeChanged, false); 

formElement = document.getElementById("textFillColor");
formElement.addEventListener('change', textFillColorChanged, false);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `addEventListener` is really relevant.  I think this is a good question in a broader context.  When is it appropriate or not appropriate to recycle variables?

Comment: When you talk about recycling variables I think that when a variable will not be used for its current content. Like say baseBallScore is not going to be used for any further score activity then it could be recylced in Javascript. But in this case the formElement is used every time to add a addEventListener(...) to a specific variable. So in this case the variable is no longer needed after it is used to add the action event listener and thusly can be recycled and used in another add event listener with out having to working about

Comment: it being used again for the action event listener that it was just used for. I think for code readability it would be better to use a different variable for each listener but I think that it does not really matter after the getElementById is called because that uses the same getElementById is the same type variable or in Javascript it is the same variable of type object.

Answer (score 0):

Like all things in software engineering, it really depends.  In this code the way it is literally written, I wouldn't even use variables since they are each used once.  I would do something like:

```
document.getElementById("canvasOne").theCanvas.getContext("2d");
document.getElementById("textBox").addEventListener('keyup', textBoxChanged, false);
document.getElementById("fillOrStroke").addEventListener('change', fillOrStrokeChanged, false);
document.getElementById("textSize").addEventListener('change', textSizeChanged, false);
document.getElementById("textFillColor").addEventListener('change', textFillColorChanged, false);
```

Of course, this assumes each variable is used once.  This is really all personal opinion, but I don't like cluttering up code with variables that are only used once, especially when each one is used in a pattern.  The pattern becomes more readable when it is done like above (in my opinion, of course).

However, I also don't like recycling variables for different purposes.  If I needed to reference a variable multiple times, like to do null checks:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');
var context;

if (canvas != null) {
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

Then I would use a separate variable for everything so that it's clear which objects exist at what times and whey they refer to at which times.